# How can I place a panel in another panel?

Tags: wxpython

How can I place a wx.Panel inside another wx.Panel? Just a small test program which doesn't work:

```
import wx

class TstApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "TstApp", wx.DefaultPosition,
        wx.DefaultSize)

        self.pn = wx.Panel(self.frame, -1)
        self.pn2 = wx.Panel(self.pn, -1)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self.pn2, -1, "A Button")

        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)

        return True

app = TstApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As phineas has already said, you should just use a sizer to arrange your widgets. But if you REALLY want to put multiple panels next to each other, then you can use a sizer for that too.

```
import random
import wx

########################################################################
class RandomPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        color = random.choice(["green", "blue", "yellow", "red"])
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        firstSubPanel = RandomPanel(self)
        secondSubPanel = RandomPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(firstSubPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(secondSubPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Panels")

        panel = MainPanel(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're completely missing the topic "layout management. I recommend reading the [layout section](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/) of the tutorial on zetcode. I've introduced `wx.BoxSizer`s to fix your example code:

```
import wx

class TstApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "TstApp", wx.DefaultPosition,
        wx.DefaultSize)

        self.pn = wx.Panel(self.frame, -1)
        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.pn.SetSizer(sizer1)

        self.pn2 = wx.Panel(self.pn, -1)
        sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.pn2.SetSizer(sizer2)
        sizer1.Add(self.pn2)

        self.btn = wx.Button(self.pn2, -1, "A Button")
        sizer2.Add(self.btn)

        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)

        return True

app = TstApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

By the way, it's better to have to do widget creation etc. in a class derived from `wx.Frame`.